# Integral of $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x-1}}$ using partial fractions.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, radicals, partial-fractions

> Find $$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x-1}}\ dx.$$

I have attempted to use the $A/x + B/\sqrt{x-1}$ method. That does not work. I have tried a substitution with $t= \sqrt{x-1}$ and $t^2 +1 = x$. Finding the $dt$ and exchanging it with $dx$ creates another square root in the denominator.

Comment: This is not a homework help site. _Please_ show what you have attempted rather than issuing commands.

Comment: do you mean $\frac{1}{x(x-1)^5}$?

Comment: I read the .5 as $\frac{1}{2}$. Apologies if this was not what OP intended.

Comment: @Nehorai By OP's attempt below, it's clear that he meant `^.5` and not `^5`.

Answer (score 4):

The choice you may have been looking for is a "rationalizing substitution",  $t^2 = x - 1$, which has the differential $2t \, dt = dx$.  The integral then becomes

$$ \int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x-1}}\, dx \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \int \frac{2 t \, dt}{ (t^2 \ + \ 1) \cdot t} = \int \frac{2}{t^2 + 1 } \, dt,$$

which also leads to the arctangent anti-derivative **Nehorai** shows.

Answer (score 2):

> $$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x-1}}\ dx.$$

Substitute $t=x-1$ and $dt=dx$

$$=\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt t(t+1)}$$

Substitute $\nu=\sqrt t$ and $d\nu=\frac{dt}{2\sqrt t}$

$$=2\int\frac{d\nu}{\nu^2+1}=2\arctan \nu+\mathcal C=2\arctan \sqrt t+\mathcal C=\color{red}{2\arctan (\sqrt{x-1})+\mathcal C}$$

Comment: "using partial fraction expansion"

Answer (score 1):

> Given that the title of the OP is "Integral of $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x-1}}$ using partial fractions," I thought it might be instructive to present a solution using partial fraction expansion.  To that end, we proceed.

Now, other answers have already been posted wherein enforcing the substitution $x=t^2+1$, the result of the integration was expressed as

$$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x-1}}\,dx=2\int \frac{1}{t^2+1}\,dt \tag 1$$

We now proceed under the assumption that one doesn't recognize the right-hand side of $(1)$ as $2\arctan(t)$, and one insists on evaluating the integral using partial fraction expansion.  Then, we can write the right-hand side of $(1)% as

$$\begin{align}
2\int \frac{1}{t^2+1}\,dt&=\frac1i \int \left(\frac{1}{t-i}-\frac{1}{t+i}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=i \log(t+i)-i\log(t-i)+C\\\\
&=\frac i2\log(t^2+1)-\arctan(1/t)-\frac i2\log(t^2+1)-\arctan(1/t)+C'\\\\
&=-2 \arctan(1/t)+C'\\\\
&=2\arctan(t)+C''
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: This is probably a good illustration of the importance of stating the context in the question post.  At the point in the typical calculus sequence where such an integral appears, $ \ t^2 \ + \ 1 \ $ would be treated as an "irreducible" quadratic polynomial (over the real numbers), so one simply wouldn't use partial fraction decomposition.  (So it would be reasonable to assume that the person posting the problem was misled -- which is what I did.)  If we extend to complex numbers, then yours is of course the response that actually answers the question!

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Yes, I agree with you.  I just thought it would be complementary to the answers that were already posted and perhaps useful for some readers to see that indeed one can use PFE.